# laravel cURL error 60 проверка капчи

Tags: php, laravel, recaptcha, laravel-8, php-curl

Я установил капчу у себя в веб-приложении и воту меня начала появляться эта ошибка.
php.ini изменил:
пробовал так:

```
cacert.cafile= "C:\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

и так:

```
openssl.cafile= "C:\php\extras\ssl\openssl.cnf"
```

Все равно не работает

Лог ошибки:

```
GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ RequestException - cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
```

Comment: Laravel, php.ini и cURL очень взаимосвязаны... вы пытаетесь получить результат cURL от сайта с https? Не пойму причем тут капча.. если это ssl

Comment: Вот лог ошибки - GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ RequestException - cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify

Comment: обратные слэши стоит либо экранировать, либо заменить на прямые.